# Чем заменить COUNT(DISTINCT...)?

Tags: sql, oracle, impala

Дано: таблица с несколькими столбцами. Мы хотим посчитать количество уникальных значений в каждом столбце. Например:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT A) A_CNT,
       COUNT(DISTINCT B) B_CNT,
       COUNT(DISTINCT C) C_CNT
  FROM MY_TABLE; -- MY_TABLE конечно не таблица в реальности, а другой запрос
```

Но вот беда, импала не умеет отрабатывать больше одного COUNT(DISTINCT...). Как бы так это хитро заменить, сложились ли у кого наиболее удачные практики?

Comment: A CTE твоя импала понимает? или и тут у неё проблемы?

Comment: Попробовать вложенными запросами, в каждом считать один count?

Comment: 1) CTE понимает =)
2) Вложенные запросы... вариант, конечно, держу как запасной, но по цене это обойдется в какие-то не реальные значения. В оригинальной задаче 7 каунт дистинктов из запроса в пол тысячи строк :)

Comment: @Akina Есть, правда, нюанс. Не поддерживаются подзапросы в SELECT-листе. Например, в оракле отработает запрос:
`WITH T AS (
 SELECT 5 A, 4 B, 7 C    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 3 A, 5 B, 1 C    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 1 A, 6 B, 2 C    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 2 A, 3 B, null C FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 3 A, 3 B, 7 C    FROM DUAL
)
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT A) FROM T) A_CNT,
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT B) FROM T) B_CNT,
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT C) FROM T) C_CNT
  FROM DUAL;`
А в импале нет (только "FROM DUAL" в импале не нужен).

Comment: @Akina
Вместо этого можно использовать запрос
`WITH T AS (
 SELECT 5 A, 4 B, 7 C    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 3 A, 5 B, 1 C    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 1 A, 6 B, 2 C    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 2 A, 3 B, null C FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 3 A, 3 B, 7 C    FROM DUAL
)
SELECT A_CNT, B_CNT, C_CNT
  FROM (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT A) A_CNT FROM T) A_CNT,
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT B) B_CNT FROM T) B_CNT,
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT C) C_CNT FROM T) C_CNT;`
p.s. Жаль в комментах форматирование ломается)

Comment: В первом CTE запрос-источник, во 2-4 подсчёт по одному COUNT(DISTINCT), в основном просто CROSS JOIN подзапросов 2-4.

Comment: Ну да, именно так я и сформировал второй запрос комментом выше (разве что подзапросы переместил из WITH секции во FROM, но тут "картошка-картофель", как я понимаю). Похоже, это единственный путь, который видится в этой ситуации.